# Webcrypto derive a RSA public key from private key in PEM encoding

Tags: javascript, rsa, private-key, public-key, webcrypto-api

I'm trying to derive a RSA public key from a given private key in PEM encoding in Webcrypto environment. I searched a lot in the web and here on SO but it seems that no easy "built-in" solution is available.

At the moment I'm doing it in 5 steps and I can't believe that there is no programmatical solution [without using additional external libraries].

Here are my steps to derive the public key

1. import the private key in pem encoding (stripping off the header and
   footer line, convert the remaining data from Base64 encoding in
   binary format
2. export the private key in jwk encoding
3. delete 5 elements in jwk object: "d"; "dp", "dq", "q", "qi" and "p"
4. import the shorted jwk as public key in jwk encoding
5. export the public key as "SPKI" with additional header and footer lines.

The used private key is an **unencrypted sample RSA private key** in PKCS8 format and this is the result of my test:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA8EmWJUZ/Osz4vXtUU2S+
0M4BP9+s423gjMjoX+qP1iCnlcRcFWxthQGN2CWSMZwR/vY9V0un/nsIxhZSWOH9
iKzqUtZD4jt35jqOTeJ3PCSr48JirVDNLet7hRT37Ovfu5iieMN7ZNpkjeIG/CfT
/QQl7R+kO/EnTmL3QjLKQNV/HhEbHS2/44x7PPoHqSqkOvl8GW0qtL39gTLWgAe8
01/w5PmcQ38CKG0oT2gdJmJqIxNmAEHkatYGHcMDtXRBpOhOSdraFj6SmPyHEmLB
ishaq7Jm8NPPNK9QcEQ3q+ERa5M6eM72PpF93g2p5cjKgyzzfoIV09Zb/LJ2aW2g
QwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

This key matches to the original public key.

My question: is there any other programmatical solution available on Webcrypto ?

Here is my rough code that has no exception handling (derive.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>SO Webcrypto derive an RSA public key from a private key in PEM encoding</title>
    <style>
        body {background-color: powderblue;}
        h1 {color: blue;}
        h2 {font-size: 200%;}
        p {font-size: 150%; }
        button {height: 100%; font-size: 150%;}
        textarea {font-size: 150%;}
        input[type="text"] {font-size: 100%; }
        input[type="button"] {font-size: 100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>SO Webcrypto derive an RSA public key from a private key in PEM encoding</h1>

<hr>
<p>my sample private key (in PEM encoding):</p>
<textarea name="privateKeyPem" id="privateKeyPem" rows="10" cols="64">-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
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
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----</textarea>
<br>
<button id="deriveRsaPublicKeyFromPrivateKeyPem" onclick="deriveRsaPublicKeyFromPrivateKeyPem()">derive public key</button>
<br>
<p>exported public key in PEM encoding:</p>
<textarea name="exportedPublicKeyPem" id="exportedPublicKeyPem" rows="10" cols="64">the exported key comes here...</textarea>
</body>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
let privateKeyInternal;
let publicKeyInternal;
let publicKeyJwkInternal;

/*
Convert a string into an ArrayBuffer
from https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String
*/
function str2ab(str) {
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
    const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
      bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
        }
    return buf;
}

function spkiToPEM(keydata){
    var keydataS = arrayBufferToString(keydata);
    var keydataB64 = window.btoa(keydataS);
    var keydataB64Pem = formatSpkiAsPem(keydataB64);
    return keydataB64Pem;
}

function arrayBufferToString( buffer ) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
    }
    return binary;
}

function formatSpkiAsPem(str) {
    var finalString = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n';
    while(str.length > 0) {
        finalString += str.substring(0, 64) + '\n';
        str = str.substring(64);
    }
    finalString = finalString + "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    return finalString;
}

// step 5 export the rsa public key in pem encoding
function exportPublicKeyPem() {
    var publicKey = publicKeyInternal;
    window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(
        "spki", // can be "jwk" (public or private), "spki" (public only), or "pkcs8" (private only)
        publicKey // can be a publicKey or privateKey, as long as extractable was true
    )
    .then(function(keydata){
        var publicKeyPem = spkiToPEM(keydata);
        document.getElementById('exportedPublicKeyPem').value = publicKeyPem;
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.error(err);
    });
}

// step 4 import the rsa public key in jwk encoding
function importPublicKeyJwk() {
    const binaryJwk = publicKeyJwkInternal;
    window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "jwk", // can be "jwk" (public or private), "spki" (public only), or "pkcs8" (private only)
        binaryJwk,
        {   // these are the algorithm options
            name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
            hash: {name: "SHA-256"}, //can be "SHA-1", "SHA-256", "SHA-384", or "SHA-512"
        },
        true, //whether the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
        ["verify"] //"verify" for public key import, "sign" for private key imports
    )
    .then(function(publicKey){
        //returns a publicKey (or privateKey if you are importing a private key)
        publicKeyInternal = publicKey;
        exportPublicKeyPem();
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.error(err);
    });
}

// step 2 export the rsa private key in jwk encoding
function exportPrivateKeyJwk() {
    var privateKey = privateKeyInternal;
    window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(
        "jwk", //can be "jwk" (public or private), "spki" (public only), or "pkcs8" (private only)
        privateKey //can be a publicKey or privateKey, as long as extractable was true
    )
    .then(function(keydata){
        // step 3 strip off some jwk elements
        // derive the public key
        // by removing private data from JWK
        delete keydata.d;
        delete keydata.dp;
        delete keydata.dq;
        delete keydata.q;
        delete keydata.qi;
        delete keydata.p;
        keydata.key_ops = ["encrypt", "verify"];
        publicKeyJwkInternal = keydata; // save the keydata in publicKeyJwkInternal
        importPublicKeyJwk();
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.error(err);
    });
}

// step 1: import rsa private key in pem encoding
function deriveRsaPublicKeyFromPrivateKeyPem() {
    var privateKeyPem = document.getElementById('privateKeyPem').value;
    var pem = privateKeyPem;
    // fetch the part of the PEM string between header and footer
    const pemHeader = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----";
    const pemFooter = "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
    const pemContents = pem.substring(pemHeader.length, pem.length - pemFooter.length);
    // base64 decode the string to get the binary data
    const binaryDerString = window.atob(pemContents);
    // convert from a binary string to an ArrayBuffer
    const binaryDer = str2ab(binaryDerString);
    // import rsa private key
    window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "pkcs8", // can be "jwk" (public or private), "spki" (public only), or "pkcs8" (private only)
        binaryDer,
        {   // these are the algorithm options
            name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
            hash: {name: "SHA-256"}, //can be "SHA-1", "SHA-256", "SHA-384", or "SHA-512"
        },
        true, //whether the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
        ["sign"] //"verify" for public key import, "sign" for private key imports
    )
    .then(function(privateKey){
        privateKeyInternal = privateKey;
        // now export the private key as jwk
        exportPrivateKeyJwk(); // the key is taken from privateKeyInternal
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.error(err);
    });
}
</SCRIPT>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to be sure, just exporting the private key as spki doesn't work? I could not find information on that...

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes: thanks for your comment and I didn't find any doc too. Regarding your question: when using the imported key (is in "privateKeyInternal" after the import) as direct input for step 5 (export the rsa public key as pem) I'm getting the error "DOMException: The key is not of the expected type". Seems that I cannot use the imported key as direct source for an export (maybe because it's not of a "type" key pair ??).

Comment: Yeah, probably. Sometimes the function is available since the public exponent is already included (and calculating the public key from an ECC private key is just point multiplication anyway). So it was an educated guess that it might be available - but apparently I guessed wrong. To be honest, I don't like the API much anyway, but I guess you got to work with what you have. Personally I think your hack is fine - I mean, it works and CPU's are fast so... One disadvantage: it won't work when you cannot export the private key.